# Trouble with Angular Animations

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following in a directive...

partial

```
<div class="row-animate" ng-repeat="item in test">
```

JS

```
scope.test = [{name:"test start"}];
scope.addNew = function(){
  scope.test.push({name:"Test other"});
}
```

Animation works great. Now I have another list, it is getting filled by a controller then passed off to my directive via data binding...

```
scope: {
  items: '='
}
<div class="row row-animate" ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy : sortColumn : sortDescending"
         ng-init="itemOrdinal = $index;"
         ng-class="{'even-item': ($index%2), 'odd-item': !($index%2)}">
```

Problem is this one just loads I see no animation. Can anyone see anything glaring I am doing wrong?

**Update**

CSS

```
.row-animate {
  color:green;
  &.ng-enter {
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 10s;
    -moz-animation: fadeIn 10s;
    -ms-animation: fadeIn 10s;
    animation: fadeIn 10s;
  }

  &.ng-leave {
    -webkit-animation: fadeOut 1s;
    -moz-animation: fadeOut 1s;
    -ms-animation: fadeOut 1s;
    animation: fadeOut 1s;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your animation supposed to be doing?

Comment: It is a simple animation from Animate.css I can add the code.

Comment: Not sure if there is something I have to be doing in my watch with $animate or something.

Comment: Can you provide a demo in a plunker?

Comment: Have you tried taking out the extra stuff in your `<div class="row row-animate"...>` and making it be just `<div class="row row-animate" ng-repeat="item in items">`?

Comment: I can provide a plunker but it will take a bit Bobo I will try that when I finish the plunker but I will eventually need the filter and removing is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have the `ngAnimate' module in your dependencies, and the js/css files loaded, as they are not included in angularjs core. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate under 'Installation'.

Comment: I have it included that does not appear to be the issue I am going to work on the plunkr and include it Tuesday.